# Replicating Excel's Solver in Python using PuLP

Tags: python, dataframe, optimization, minimize, pulp

First of all thank you very much in advance. I am struggling in an optimization problem. In my model I do 10 simulations of options return, that will be multiplied by the respective weights thus resulting in a portfolio return and consequently a utility value. The objective is to find the optimal weights that maximize average utility through the different simulations.

**Before:**

Problem:

- structuring my problem (AVERAGE(H3:H12)) and variables (C14:G14)
- Coding my constraints visible in the image below
  [image]

**After:**

[image]

This is the result the Solver yields.

The used dataset is

`````
```df=pd.DataFrame({'Risk Free Rate':[0.001,0.001,0.001,0.001,0.001,0.001,0.001,0.001,0.001,0.001],
             'Call ATM Ask':[0.01,0.02,0.03,-1,-1,0.01,0.005,0.006,0.06,-1],
             'Call ATM Bid':[-0.01,-0.02,-0.03,1,1,-0.01,-0.005,-0.006,-0.06,1],
             'Put ATM Ask':[-1,-1,-1,0.1,0.15,-1,-1,-1,-1,0.05],
             'Put ATM Bid':[1,1,1,-0.1,-0.15,1,1,1,1,0.05]})````
`````

Thank you very much

Comment: Maybe reading [the docs](https://pypi.org/project/PuLP/) might help. It should be pretty straightfoward

Comment: The constraints you create in lines 18 and 19 are not linear. Thus these can't be implemented in this way using pulp. But when I see this correctly the two columns are exactly the negated of the other. So each optimal basis solution should only have one of the two anyways, thus you might just drop these constraints.

Comment: I read the docs and the main struggle is that the variable (weights) are a 1 by 5 array while returns are a 10 by 5 array. I'm struggling to structure the problem given my situation. Thank you for the advice though!

Comment: I already tried it with scipy but i get several solutions where this constraint is not respected. I can either have a positive weight on the ask or the bid. If the ask weight is positive, the the bid's must be 0 and vice-versa.

Comment: Did I see correctly that there is a power in you utility function?

Comment: SimonT yes! That is correct